# Is simultaneous diophantine approximation (in a weaker sense) NP hard?

Tags: computational-complexity, diophantine-approximation

The traditional problem of simultaneous diophantine approximation is:  Given a set of rational numbers $g_1,\ldots,g_d$, an integer $N$, and a rational $\gamma>0$, is  there an integer $W$ with $1\le W\le N$ such that
$$\forall i\ \min_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} |Wg_i - n| < \gamma\ ?$$
This problem was shown to be NP-complete by Lagarias. ("The computational complexity of simultaneous diophantine approximation problems", SIAM J. Comput., 14(1):196–209, Feb. 1985.)

With the same inputs, we can also ask:  Is there $W$ such that
$$\forall i\ \min_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} |g_i - n/W|<\gamma\ ?$$

Is it still an NP-complete problem to find a good diophantine approximation in this sense? Thanks!

Comment: The question does not make sense as written: NP is a class of decision problems, not search problems, and one cannot represent arbitrary reals by finite strings as there are uncountably many. The problem shown NP-complete by Lagarias is to determine whether there *exists* such a $W$, and it has *rational* $\alpha,\gamma$ as input. Is this what you want?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: you are right, sorry, I was not precise enough. I've fixed the question.

Comment: OK. I haven’t studied Lagarias paper in detail, but my gut feeling is that it should still be NP-complete. Did you try to play a bit with the reduction in his argument to see whether it might yield this? (It might even be simpler than the original.)

Comment: To be honest, I'm "just an engineer", but my mathematician friends tried to do so, but they gave up, the proof was too complicated, they said...

Comment: Related: http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2009/08/01/the-chinese-remainder-theorem-with-limits/